Python Regex Query To Pull Out A Name
I'm trying to pull out just the persons name of the below text, I've tried the below on regex101 with no look so far, any help greatly appreciated.
Owner:\s(.*)

https://regex101.com/r/3xjoAU/2
I'm trying to just pull out any string for a person's name that is where Tom_Cook is when the string Owner is present only.
Test Strings:
Owner: Tom_Cook
Owner: Tom_Cook, Test
Owner: Tom_Cook Test
Tom_Cook, Test
Tom Cook, Test
Test


Is Owner: Tom Cook, Test a possible input?

@Barmar, it shoudn't be so it should be ignored.

Your regexp needs to stop matching at the , character, so that Test isn't included in the name.
Owner:\s([^,\n\s]+)

Or instead of specifying the character to stop at, use a character set to match the characters to allow, which appears to be just letters and underscore.
Owner:\s([a-zA-Z_]+)


Owner:\s([^,\n\s]*) is needed to stop matching at the space after Tom_Cook in the 3rd example.
